# How do I work from the LHS to get to the RHS $(2 - 1/n) + (1/(n+1)^2) = (2-((n+1)^2 - n)) / n((n+1))^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\bigg[2 - \frac{1}{n}\bigg] + \bigg[\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg] = 2-\frac{(n+1)^2 - n}{ n(n+1)^2}$$

How do I get the left side look like right side with few extra steps? It's part of  an induction proof and I'm stuck there.

Comment: Once you use the correct formatting, it should be obvious that you just use $$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$

Comment: I fear equations alone are not appropriated titles. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigg[2-\frac{1}{n}\bigg]+\bigg[\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg]=2+\bigg[-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg]$$
$$=2+\bigg[-\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+1)^2}+\frac{n}{n(n+1)^2}\bigg]=2+\frac{-(n+1)^2+n}{n(n+1)^2}=2-\frac{(n+1)^2-n}{n(n+1)^2}$$